PDF scaled to reflect counts (size of the sample) does not align with Histogram's range
Mock data:
sample1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], size1 = 115];
sample2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1], size2 = 57];
sample3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 1], size3 = 99];
sample4 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[3, 1], size4 = 12];
dist = MixtureDistribution[{size1, size2, size3, size4}/(size1 + size2 + size3 + size4), {NormalDistribution[0, 1], NormalDistribution[1, 1], NormalDistribution[2, 1], NormalDistribution[3, 1]}];

The sample size is
size = size1 + size2 + size3 + size4


283

Both Histograms for the joint sample and the "Stacked" one are the same, but when I add Plot[size PDF[dist, x], {x, -4, 4}] there's a discrepancy:
Show[Histogram[Join[sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4], Automatic, "Count", ChartStyle -> Gray], Plot[size PDF[dist, x], {x, -4, 4}]]
Show[Histogram[{sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4}, Automatic, "Count", ChartLayout -> "Stacked"], Plot[size PDF[dist, x], {x, -4, 4}]]


What's wrong here and how to make it right?
If I change "Count" to "PDF" (and get rid of size when Plotting the PDF) then it aligns for the joint sample, but the "Stacked" Histogram looks different than the one of the joint sample, and the PDF doesn't align, too:
Show[Histogram[Join[sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4], Automatic, "PDF", ChartStyle -> Gray], Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, -4, 4}]]
Show[Histogram[{sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4}, Automatic, "PDF", ChartLayout -> "Stacked"], Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, -4, 4}]]



$Version


"13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"


It appears that the shape of the lower-right colored histogram differs from the gray lower-left one.

@RomkeBontekoe Yes, like I wrote: "If I change "Count" to "PDF" (...) the "Stacked" Histogram looks different" - I meant "compared to the joint one". I'll edit.

It's all about having equal areas so one needs to multiply the pdf by the product of the sample size and the bin width.  As such this is not a Mathematica issue and so I am voting to close.  But I'll retract that vote if someone makes a good case otherwise.

@JimB Agreed. I naively expected Mathematica to take the bin width into account automatically.

Here is a fix if the Automatic bandwidth is chosen.  The fix is to equalize the areas under the pdf and the histogram.
(* Determine the Automatic binwidth *)
binwidth = Differences[HistogramList[Join[sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4]][[1]]][[1]]

(* Produce histograms *)
h1 = Histogram[Join[sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4], Automatic, "Count", ChartStyle -> Gray];
h2 = Histogram[{sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4}, Automatic, "Count", ChartLayout -> "Stacked"];
Show[h1, Plot[size * binwidth * PDF[dist, x], {x, -4, 4}]]


Show[h2, Plot[size * binwidth * PDF[dist, x], {x, -4, 4}]]


As some might know, I think stacked bar charts and stacked histograms should either be banned or rarely used.
